# Filter Only The Data Which Don't have any Previous Transaction

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to query only the data which don't have any Previous Transaction

```
This is the Query Result
    sku    barcode     details      load_dt
    546    a674        testabc2     2021-10-21
    546    a674        testabc2     2021-10-17
    111    a111        test1111     2021-10-21
    111    a111        test1111     2021-10-20
    333    a333        test3333     2021-10-21
    444    a444        test4444     2021-10-21

Expected Result
    sku    barcode     details      load_dt
    333    a333        test3333     2021-10-21
    444    a444        test4444     2021-10-21
```

Comment: what have you tried so far? hint `not exists`

Comment: hi mastashufu not yet, maybe I would try to search some info on how to use not exist method.

Hi dale I don't have any idea for this so far, I just Post this Question to gain ideas from expert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to filter data that has only 1 row

```
SELECT * FROM trans WHERE sku IN (
SELECT sku
FROM trans
GROUP BY sku
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

Here, I create [dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3rPMcxHTZrc88oejP2dDbL/0)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a windowed `COUNT` for this. It is usually more efficient than a correlated subquery

```sql
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY sku)
    FROM trans
) trans
WHERE count = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=fe4681d7d76d1b536c4f84291129ac3d)